# IE rendering trailing white space at end of each line

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rendering, whitespace, webfonts

I've got a web font that includes it's own underline, including on the space character. This renders fine in almost all browsers, the underline is shown between words but it not rendered at the end of the line — except in IE (all versions).

In IE it's displaying the extra underlined space at the end of every line, except for the last. Even if I use a line break, with no spaces at all, it still displays.

I've tried all variations of the white-space property, to no effect. Has anyone else encountered this weird display bug, and know of anyway to fix it?

Edit:
[Example Page](http://sector7g.com.au/clients/test/whitespace.html)
[Screenshot](http://sector7g.com.au/clients/test/whitespace.png)

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe we did, maybe not, but can you provide the HTML and CSS? Or a live link?

Comment: Thanks for your response @user1627363 I can't include the actual page due to confidentiality, but have done a trimmed down example page with just the text and the bug. Added the link to the page, and a screenshot, to my original post.

Comment: Please show code on page and link to screenshot into page.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to solve the problem... make it an image.

How text is rendered depends on a lot of factors, like the fonts installed, operating system, rendering `calibration`, `font smoothing` and rendering parameters. If any of those parameters differ, the result differs.

If you examine your image, you will see that the browsers use different parameters for font smoothing, and other parameters may also differ.

You simply can't expect an identical result when rendering text in different browsers.